# Display data with accent french in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, encoding, utf-8

I have data with accents in my database. like image below
[image]

when I want to display the data with my controller it gives me this 
Here is the code

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$icozim=$this->Icozim->find('all');
debug($icozim,0,0);
```

when I run my function I have this
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

sql for my table is

```
    CREATE TABLE `icozims` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `synonymes` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What encoding is the database using? How did you put the data in there?

Comment: It may be as simple as changing the font that's used to view the debug information.

Comment: @Wooble I use utf8_general_ci and i put data manually

Comment: @AnthonyAtkinson how i can do that?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196176/utf-8-output-with-cakephp)

Answer (score 4):

In your `APP/Config/database.php` look for the line:

```
// 'encoding' => 'utf8',
```

and uncomment it.

Comment: i have this error if i uncomment this line Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in C:\wamp\www\look\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Mysql.php on line 146

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424343/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-with-pdo @TiAmoLaky

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you have to cover. All of these Encode has to be the same (assigned properly). then you can retrieve symbols or special characters properly.

1. Encode that you are using for Database
2. At the same time Encode you are using for Table
3. Encode of your HTML header
4. Encode of php code when ever you are retrieving/ printing / saving your data.
   Also there are some functions that you can play around which does that for you.
   e.g. mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')
5. If you are using any kind of frameworks you might need to set the Encode in core class
6. If your data has been saved with this specific symbol then you will need to edit all of them or write a function to convert them to a symbol or character you want to show. I remember I had the same problem with one of my project with wordpress which we removed all manually but after that I find an article that there was a plugin which sort out that problem automatically for you.